# F12Chooser.exe not running after windows 10 updated

Tags: windows-10, developer-tools, ie-developer-tools

I develop Excel tab-pane addin(office.js api) and use F12Chooser tool for debugging.
After upgrade Windows 10 to build 14342.1001 I can't run F12Chooser.exe from:
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\F12Chooser.exe` and `C:\Windows\System32\F12\F12Chooser.exe`
After double-click the mouse cursor quickly flashes and nothing happened. When try run from context menu in Excel web view still nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

(This is an old post so replying in case anyone else finds it usefull.)

You can file a bug/feedback on F12Chooser in the Feedback Hub (search for it in start). If you place it in the Microsoft Edge -> Developer Tools category it should get routed to the right people.

As a workaround if you have Visual Studio 2017 installed you can use that to attach the script debugger to any process from the attach to process menu (changing the debug engine to script). VS2017 has the same tools as F12 (e.g. the DOM Explorer and Console etc.).